# how can I fetch column name and its data using query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can I retrieve the column name and its particular data as two column values .Its possible to fetch column name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.Can we get
the data also with the same query like 
     set @tsql = 'select '+@col +' = Column_name,(select @col from @tablename) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_name like '''+@tablename+'''
    exec(@tsql);
Or can we put for loop inside the stored procedure

Comment: You can send bytes from C# and convert bytes to image in andrioid.

Answer (score 1):

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    return  ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
     Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
     return returnImage;
}
```